# Use of inserted and deleted tables for logging - is my concept sound?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with a simple identity column primary key. I have written a 'For Update' trigger that, among other things, is supposed to log the changes of certain columns to a log table. Needless to say, this is the first time I've tried this.

**Essentially as follows:**

```
Declare Cursor1 Cursor for 
     select a.*, b.* 
     from inserted a 
     inner join deleted b on a.OrderItemId = b.OrderItemId
```

(where `OrderItemId` is the actual name of the primary identity key).

I then do the usual open the cursor and go into a fetch next loop. With the columns I want to test, I do:

if Update(Field1)
   begin
          ..... do some logging
   end

The columns include varchars, bits, and datetimes. It works, sometimes. The problem is that the log function is writing the a and b values of the field to a log and in some cases, it appears that the before and after values are identical.

I have 2 questions:

- Am I using the Update function correctly?
- Am I accessing the before and after values correctly?
- Is there a better way?

Comment: You should try **really hard** to **AVOID** having a **cursor** inside a trigger. A trigger should be very small, nimble, fast - and a cursor is anything but...... I'd suggest you'd invest time in investigating **set-based** approaches - doing `INSERT INTO ..... ` with a `SELECT` that tests to see whether or not the column in `deleted d` is different from column in `inserted i`: `.....WHERE d.Column <> i.Column` and if that's the case, the data is being inserted.

Comment: @marc_s Thank you for contributing your precious time, I will invest my time to study set-based approaches.

Comment: Here's a good blog post on set based triggers: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/05/the-silent-bug-i-find-in-most-triggers/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server 2016 or higher, I would recommend skipping this trigger entirely and instead using [system-versioned temporal tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-2017).

Not only will it eliminate the need for (and performance issues around) the trigger, it'll be easier to query the historical data.